# Deny access to non-existing sub-paths that bubble up to an existing node

Tags: nodes

I have a drupal site with a page 'About us' (url: `example.com/about-us`). So when you type the url it correctly opens up the 'About Us' page. But if you append that url with any garbage value or a sensible word (eg:  `example.com/about-us/adfasd` OR `/home`) it still opens up the 'About us' page.

Is there a way to restrict this? 
That means the user should get an error (something like 'Page not found') if he enters a url for a page which is not valid or if there is not content for that url on the website.

Any kind of help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

check admin/config/system/site-information and configure, in my site it's empty and all wrong urls get a drupal msg that the page couldn't be found.

Comment: That page contains quite some textfields. What specifically is empty and what do you recommend setting it to?

Comment: Hey Belba, thanks for your response.But the solution you mentioned does not handle the situation.